# How to create SRV record in Linux(Bind9)?

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, bind

I am able to successfully implement **DNS** with an A record. Now I want to use that to create an **SRV** record.

Please help me to write the SRV record. I want "fs1" to be primary and when "fs1" is not responding SRV will return "fs2"

`fs1 A 192.168.60.163 fs2 A 192.168.60.161`

**192.168.60.162** is my DNS system

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: 1) please avoid using images and links and 2) you might want to learn more about what an `SRV` record is or explain what you are attempting to do because `SRV` records need to specify a protocol and a service name, you don't need just an hostname. And you need a port value too. All things that make no sense in general, you have to specify what you want to use `SRV` for.

Comment: SRV records typically  look like `_Service._Proto.Name TTL Class SRV Priority Weight Port Target` but you need an application that understands SRV records for them to have the effect that you seek.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the name "freeswitch" I assume you are asking to create SRV records for the SIP. The question is formulated in a way as if it asks for *any* SRV record; I'll use SIP as an example.

SIP uses UDP and its corresponding service name in the DNS is `sip`. Therefore, the precise record names would be `_sip._udp.example.com`.

Other part of this is your misunderstanding *who* selects the particular record to use. It is impossible to set it up so "when fs1 is not responding SRV will return fs2". DNS server doesn't do any health checks and doesn't know anything about server status; it simply answers with records, so it will always return all records associated with the requested name.

It is the *client* who always receives *both* records implements fallback logic based on the record data. We''ll set up *priority* fields in records so that *conforming* client will try fs1 first and if it won't work it will try fs2. Priority works so that lower numerically value is more preferred.

Long story short, these are records:

```
_sip._udp.example.com. SRV 10 100 5060 fs1.example.com.
_sip._udp.example.com. SRV 20 100 5060 fs2.example.com.
```

Notice you specify *hostnames* in the last field. We define SIP UDP service on the port 5060; if your servers are configured to use another port, change it in records.

100 is *weight* field. In this case it does nothing and it its value is not important, since we have just one record for each priority; in more complex configurations it allows to spread load in proportion to specified weights.

Most important are the *priority* field values. For one records it is 10, for another it is 20, so the server with value 10 should be tried first, and if it doesn't respond the client expected to try another one. However, keep in mind that *doesn't respond* could be caused by transient network problems; servers simply don't know their status as perceived by each client. So, don't assume any particular client behavior and set up servers in a way that fs2 is completely capable to handle a client, even when fs1 seems fully operational. The logic here is simple: it's published, therefore it's functional.